# Vue3 does not update new code after deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, vuejs3, aws-amplify, vite

I have Vue3 project setup by Vite. I use Aws Amplify to deploy it on production. The problem is every time I update code, when deploy success I try to refresh browser but it did not show new code. I need remove cache by hold CMD + SHIFT + R on browser chrome, so I can view the new update.

My config is keep default from Amplify and Vue3 setup. So anyone can help me.

Comment: I think it is the normal behavior of the browser when it caches some webpage. You should look through the response header of your request (HTML, js, CSS) in the browser network tab to find out which request is cached by the browser. To do it, first, you need some knowledge about caching (server, CDN, browser).

Answer (score 0):

- have you tested in the Incognito mode?
- is CloudFront being used? can you check if your deployment will invalidate what's being cached by CloudFront? you can manually invalidate the cache (https://christinavhastenrath.medium.com/how-to-manually-invalidate-aws-cloudfront-b36a2ab4e1be) and test if you can get the updates in the browser.